# Is this method for approximating pi valid?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, pi, programming

So I have an n-gon inscribed in a circle of radius 1. 
So the interior angles of an n-gon are 180*(n-2). Dividing this by n, I would obtain each individual interior angle. From here, using trig functions like sine/cosine, I could get coordinates of two points that form an edge, calculate distance between them, then multiply that distance by n to obtain the perimeter of the n-gon. Then as n grows large, the perimeter would approximate pi*diameter.

My question is, is this a valid way to approximate pi? By coding and running a program like this, am I just using the preprogrammed values of pi in calculating pi by using trig functions? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a good way to approximate $\pi$. However, this is expressible in a nice limit form, once you simplify all the coordinate forms: $\lim_{N \to \infty} N \sin\frac \pi N  = \pi$.

Comment: But is it valid? Because using 360 instead of 2pi is just a matter of using degrees or radians for the trig functions, so technically I'm using built in trig functions to calculate pi?

Comment: I originally said, So sum of interior angles of an n gon is 
pi * n -2pi, so pi*(n-2).

Then each interior angle is pi*(n-2)/n.

So take angle ABC of square ABCD, with radius(?)-distance from the center to each corner- of 1.
The cosine of half ABC is half the length of one edge of the square. 


Then 2 cos (pi*(n-2)/2n) * n is the perimeter of the n gon.
Then as n gets really large, this value approaches 2 pi, since the radius is 1 and circumference is pi * 2r. At this point I realized I used pi to approximate pi... But would doing this same process with degrees work?

Comment: Exactly, Thus, you are able to approximate the value of $\pi$ using this formula.And with degrees, it would not work, because the limits wold approach a different constant.

Comment: Archimedes used inscribed polygons to approximate pi centuries before it was ever programmed into a computer... he did use some approximations to various square roots, but that doesn't require pi. I don't know the details of his method, but you could look into it. There might be a way to get around using trig functions.

Comment: @kccu Yeah, do you think using trig functions just renders the whole thing invalid? I'm just kinda confused. And if degrees works but radians doesn't, that's even more confusing since they're just a constant multiple of one another.

Comment: @DZD Whether you are using degrees or radians, you are making use of trig tables which inherently store information about the value of pi. This page might be useful: it talks about how to get around using trig functions: https://betterexplained.com/articles/prehistoric-calculus-discovering-pi/.

Comment: @kccu thanks! If I could just figure out how to get the coordinates without using pi...

Comment: Minor correction: They formula for sum of interior angles is 180(n-2), not 360(n-2). I would edit the question, but SE does not allow edits that are less than 6 characters.

Comment: My bad, I meant that. Fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is a valid one, and your worries have some base. Let me explain.

As pointed out in the comments, the method of approximating $\pi$ using inscribed and circumscribed regular polygons with more and more edges, goes as far back as Archimedes. Well done for thinking the general method.

The big question of course is how do you calculate the side of a regular $n$-gon. You can do it by using trigonometric functions, but then this transfers the problem to how do you calculate the values for $sin(x)$ or $cos(x)$. You can use the built-in functions in any programming languages to get the values, as you mention. But these are black boxes to you, so you are *right to be skeptical* about what's going on inside. If, for example, these implementations use approximations of $\pi$ to begin with, this would defeat the purpose. So again, well done on your intuition.

It is difficult to find out what's going on in a particular implementation of a math library of your programming language of choice (see [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions) to get an idea). They usually rely on a variety on precomputed tables, trig relationships, and power series. For example, they could rely on this power series:
$$sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} -\frac{x^7}{7!} +\frac{x^9}{9!} - \dots$$
$x$ here is expressed in radians, so you need to know $\pi$ to do this.
The precomputed values, do not necessarily have to rely on $\pi$. See this [great educational page](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/trig/compute.html) on how trig tables used to be computed in antiquity.

Even if $\pi$ is not used in modern implementations of $sin$ and $cos$ functions in computers (which seems unlikely) there are other issues. These implementations have certain **accuracy** limitations, so for example, it might not make sense to use them to approximate $\pi$ using a $1000$-gon. So without knowing in depth what these implementations are doing it's hard to justify their usage in this approximation task.

But there are good news. You don't have to use these implementations. You do not have to take arbitrary $n$-gons to approximate $\pi$, you just want them to have a large $n$. So you can choose your $n$ to result in easily computable $sin$. We know that $sin(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and that $sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$. We also know the $sin$ formulas for **half angles**. So find the $n$-gons that have the "easy" angles to compute. This way you can approximate $\pi$ arbitrarily close, using only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square root.

Comment: Hmm you make some interesting points. Thank you!

Comment: @DZD Or you can use series' that sum upto pi. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html

Comment: @DZD if you think this answer is useful and more or less complete, you can accept it (apart from upvoting). I am just mentioning this because I see you are a new user.

Comment: @DZD On the left side of the question where you can see the points (and the upvote and downvote arrows) there should be a grey tick (a checkmark) under the downvote arrow. Press and it will become green, this means that you accepted the answer.

Comment: Some details: $N \sin(\pi/N) \geq N (\pi/N - \pi^3/(6N^3))=\pi-\pi^3/(6N^2)$. So we want $N$ such that $\frac{\frac{\pi^3}{6N^2}}{\pi}=\frac{\pi^2}{6N^2}$ is small enough so that our relative error in $\pi$ is good. If we know in advance that, say, $\pi^2 \leq 12$, then it is enough to have $\frac{2}{N^2}$ less than our tolerance, so $N \geq \left ( \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right )^{-1/2}$.

Comment: (Cont.) As a result, each application of the half-angle formula (starting with knowing $\sin(\pi/6)=1/2,\cos(\pi/6)=\sqrt{3}/2$) gives you roughly two additional binary digits. This isn't actually very fast, as approximation methods for $\pi$ go, especially since you will need to calculate many square roots. Still, it's not bad.

Comment: Actually, having played with it, this method works poorly in floating point arithmetic. The problem is that it takes a number $y$ which is very close to $1$, namely the result of applying $\sqrt{(1+x)/2}$ to $\sqrt{3}/2$ a bunch of times, and then computes a big number times $\sqrt{(1-y)/2}$. So in floating point arithmetic, after enough iterations, you wind up with just zero instead of a good answer, because $y$ becomes too close to $1$ to easily resolve the difference.